# How can I find capacity of stadium using Java?

Tags: java, computer-science

This is the question

> Write a method atCapacity(int people, int capacity) that returns a boolean determining if a stadium is at maximum capacity. A stadium is at capacity if at least 80% of the seats are sold out.

Here's the code I tried

```
public class Scratchpad
{
    atCapacity(int people, int capacity)
    {
        boolean atCapacity = false;
        capacity = people * (80/100);
    
        if(people > capacity)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(people <= capacity)
        {
        return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The code checker says

> "Grader.java: Line 4: invalid method declaration; return type
> required"

I don't understand how to fix the code. I'm not asking for answers I just need a nudge in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: you're missing return type `atCapacity(int people, int capacity)` => `boolean atCapacity(int people, int capacity)`

Comment: Your code does not match the error message.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to understand `return people >= capacity * 0.8` rather than the if blocks?

Comment: You provided code for class Scratchpad but your error is for Grader.java.

Comment: @RichardBarker omg... thank u so much it worked perfectly

Comment: Wasn't me, give the credit to the guy that showed you your syntax error.

Comment: @Vishal thats what the website i use provided as an output,

Answer (score 2):

This is supposed to be a method declaration:

```
    atCapacity(int people, int capacity)
```

But the syntax for a method declaration requires a return type, as in

```
    SomeReturnType atCapacity(int people, int capacity)
```

If we look at the body of the method you are returning `true` and `false` so the correct type should be the type of `true` and `false`, which is `<nudge>`

---

I can see some other errors too (`<nudges>`):

- The compiler will tell you that you need a `return` at the end of the method.  (It is not going to deduce that `people > capacity` and `people <= capacity` are mutually exclusive.)

  There is more than one way of solving that conundrum.
- At runtime, `80/100` is going to cause you grief; see [Int division: Why is the result of 1/3 == 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450).
- On the top of that, you have a variable called `atCapacity` which doesn't appear to be needed.

Answer (score 1):

you could write

```
public boolean atCapacity() { ... }
```

Comment: I love stack for features like that

Comment: Sorry,i just started to use stack over flow。i will be careful to add comment

Comment: I started with an erroneous comment，then i edited it